# Flow router ssr , meteor and material ui

Tags: meteor, reactjs, material-ui, flow-router

Im using meteor 1.4 and material ui with react and im getting this error

`warning.js:36 Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server:`

`(client) ;width:100%;display:flex;padding-left:24
 (server) ;width:100%;display:-webkit-box,-moz-box`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [this issue was discussed here](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/2336)

You need to use the same `process.env.NODE_ENV` on the client and on the server.

Solution: use webpack (or browserify) :

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
process: {
    env: {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    }
}})
```

For more info: http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/server-rendering

Answer (score 0):

You need to find what makes the server render something different than the client. I guess in material-ui there is like a browser switch on certain features. Once you have found that, I can help more.